# How to remove duplicates items from the list in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

The list is,

```
{id: 11, type: "sell", quantity: 11, price: 155}
{id: 11, type: "sell", quantity: 11, price: 155}
{id: 11, type: "sell", quantity: 11, price: 155}
{id: 12, type: "buy", quantity: 3, price: 189}
{id: 13, type: "buy", quantity: 4, price: 189}
{id: 14, type: "buy", quantity: 2, price: 189}
{id: 14, type: "buy", quantity: 2, price: 189}
```

(almost 1000 items)
I want to remove duplicates items from the list in javascript, for example, as items of id 11 and 14 having duplicates, so the new list will be after removing,

```
  {id: 12, type: "buy", quantity: 3, price: 189}
    {id: 13, type: "buy", quantity: 4, price: 189}
```

The duplicates item will be completely deleted in the new array its not like it will be still there in the new array

Comment: So the new array would have all the entries which had no duplicates (if had duplicate, do not display)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicates from an array of objects in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/remove-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: Did you make an attempt?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @Georgy yes the new array, would not have any duplicates, completely removed in the new array

Comment: Please see my response for an ES6 compatible answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) as closure over the already visited `id` and remove this object from the result set, if exists.

This approach uses a single loop for the data and for each found duplicate a filtering.

```js
var array = [{ id: 11, type: "sell", quantity: 11, price: 155 }, { id: 11, type: "sell", quantity: 11, price: 155 }, { id: 11, type: "sell", quantity: 11, price: 155 }, { id: 12, type: "buy", quantity: 3, price: 189 }, { id: 13, type: "buy", quantity: 4, price: 189 }, { id: 14, type: "buy", quantity: 2, price: 189 }, { id: 14, type: "buy", quantity: 2, price: 189 }],
    single = array.reduce((s => (r, o) => {
        if (s.has(o.id)) {
            return r.filter(({ id }) => id !== o.id);
        }
        s.add(o.id);
        r.push(o);
        return r;
    })(new Set), []);

console.log(single);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to hash the items after converting them to strings and see if they already exist in the destination array, if not then add them.

```js
String.prototype.hashCode = function() {
  var hash = 0, i, chr;
  if (this.length === 0) return hash;
  for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    chr   = this.charCodeAt(i);
    hash  = ((hash << 5) - hash) + chr;
    hash |= 0; // Convert to 32bit integer
  }
  return hash;
};

Array.prototype.isUnique = function(obj){
 if (this.length <= 0)
   return true;
    
 let hash = JSON.stringify(obj).hashCode();
 return !this.some(function(e){
  return JSON.stringify(e).hashCode() === hash;
 });
}

let test = [{id: 11, type: "sell", quantity: 11, price: 155},
{id: 11, type: "sell", quantity: 11, price: 155},
{id: 11, type: "sell", quantity: 11, price: 155},
{id: 12, type: "buy", quantity: 3, price: 189},
{id: 13, type: "buy", quantity: 4, price: 189},
{id: 14, type: "buy", quantity: 2, price: 189},
{id: 14, type: "buy", quantity: 2, price: 189}];


let out = [];

test.forEach(function(item){
 if (out.isUnique(item))
  out.push(item);
});

console.log(out);
```

Comment: While this answer solves the problem, it's not really *that* simple and also not really that performant.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been downvoted, but I don't think I've ever really seen a succinct answer on how to do this with object keys. If you don't need IE11, this answer should work. It uses the ES6 [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) function.

```js
function removeDuplicatesFromArray(arr){
  let unique_array = arr.filter(function(elem, index, self) {
      let firstOccurence = self.findIndex(elem => elem.id == self[index].id)
      return firstOccurence == index;
  });

  return unique_array
}

var duplicatesArr = [{id: 11, type: "sell", quantity: 11, price: 155},
{id: 11, type: "sell", quantity: 11, price: 155},
{id: 11, type: "sell", quantity: 11, price: 155},
{id: 12, type: "buy", quantity: 3, price: 189},
{id: 13, type: "buy", quantity: 4, price: 189},
{id: 14, type: "buy", quantity: 2, price: 189},
{id: 14, type: "buy", quantity: 2, price: 189}]


console.log(removeDuplicatesFromArray(duplicatesArr));
```

**Also:**

I would recommend checking out some of the other built in Array functions available. Most of them are ES2015, and therefore compatible with IE11. My specific answer used [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), but you could have also used [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), among others.